# Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-gradle-serialization-plugin:0.5.1

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I have some problems with the android project, when I try to sync project with Gradle files, the console log, display this error

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'GlobalApp'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath.
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-gradle-serialization-plugin:0.5.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-gradle-serialization-plugin:0.5.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-gradle-serialization-plugin/0.5.1/kotlinx-gradle-serialization-plugin-0.5.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-gradle-serialization-plugin/0.5.1/kotlinx-gradle-serialization-plugin-0.5.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

And actually when I try to load de URL , https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx/org/jetbrains/kotlinx/kotlinx-gradle-serialization-plugin/0.5.1/kotlinx-gradle-serialization-plugin-0.5.1.pom the response is a 403

I don't know if exist another repository or how to fix this?

They are my build.gradle files

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'
    ext.serialization_version = '0.5.1'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-gradle-serialization-plugin:$serialization_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sisvol.app.globalappkcr"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName '2.39.0'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", "GlobalApp-JSM-ST8050B-$versionName")
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:$serialization_version"
    //implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation files('libs/core-3.2.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/top-usdk-service-1.0.2.jar')
}
 ``
```

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'
ext.serialization_version = '0.5.1'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlinx/" }
}
```

Change the url of maven by: https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlinx/